# ngrok binary file execution is not working on catalina(mac os)

Tags: macos, binary, macos-catalina, ngrok

Recently i have updated to Catalina and when i have tried running ngrok below error comes in:

```
-bash: ./ngrok: cannot execute binary file
```

Below are the details of file and system:

```
cmd:- file ./ngrok
output:- ./ngrok: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, Go BuildID=WiQDkmDKISYhEPN12k-3/C6vlWFNDOR0o0u0x3X26/VIi6gzoMVXoqHTYgeFTz/LKswZ3xo2O5g2OnUiOwZ, not stripped

cmd:- uname -a
output:- Darwin XXXXXXX-MacBook-Air.local 19.2.0 Darwin Kernel Version 19.2.0: Sat Nov  9 03:47:04 PST 2019; root:xnu-6153.61.1~20/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

Any update would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was an access permission issue but this npm module solves it https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngrok, now it working smoothly.